# File Upload and automatically save into attachment

Tags: salesforce1-app, developer-console, doctype

I have created visualforce which displays to upload file and save button functionality. I have used  to upload and its working properly in salesforce1 by clicking on save. 
Now I want to change the functionality like once i upload the Image then automatically it could save into the attachement.
Can anyone suggest me how we can achieve this or anyone have snippet code.
It would be great help.

Comment: Please edit your question and share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:code snippet

Vf:

```
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Attachments" collapsible="false">


         <apex:actionFunction name="ChangeCount" action="{!ChangeCount}"/>

         <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="How many files you want to upload?"/>
                <apex:selectList onchange="ChangeCount() ;" multiselect="false" size="1" value="{!FileCount}">
                    <apex:selectOption itemLabel="None" itemValue=""/>
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!filesCountList}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
         </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

     </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Select Files" rendered="{!IF(FileCount != null && FileCount != '', true , false)}">
            <apex:repeat value="{!allFileList}" var="AFL">
                <apex:inputfile value="{!AFL.body}" filename="{!AFL.Name}" />
                <br/>
            </apex:repeat>
           </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Apex:

```
public class MultipleUploadController {


public List<SelectOption> filesCountList {get; set;}
public String FileCount {get; set;}
Public maxip__c mxv{get;set;}
public List<Attachment> allFileList {get; set;}
public boolean extn;

public MultipleUploadController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

     mxv = New maxip__c();
    filesCountList = new List<SelectOption>() ;
    FileCount = '' ;
    allFileList = new List<Attachment>() ;

    for(Integer i = 1 ; i < 11 ; i++)
       filesCountList.add(new SelectOption(''+i , ''+i)) ;
}


public Pagereference SaveAttachments()
{
    try{

    String accId = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('id');
     if(mxv.Name== null || mxv.Name == '')
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Please select Name'));
      if(mxv.Issue_Date__c < mxv.Filling_Date__c )
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'issue date should be greater than filling date'));   
   // if(FileCount == null || FileCount == '')
     //   ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Please select how many files you want to upload.'));
       insert mxv;
    List<Attachment> listToInsert = new List<Attachment>() ;


    for(Attachment a: allFileList)
    {
        if(a.name != '' && a.name != '' && a.body != null)
            listToInsert.add(new Attachment(parentId = mxv.id, name = a.name, body = a.body)) ;
    }



      for(Attachment a: listToInsert ){
             if(a.name.toUpperCase().contains('DOC') || a.name.toUpperCase().contains('DOCX') )
                  {
                 system.debug('Image is of type jpg or jpeg');
                 ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error, 'doc will not acept Error'));
                 extn= false;
                return null;
                 }


            else if(a.name.toUpperCase().contains('JPG') || a.name.toUpperCase().contains('JPEG') || a.name.toUpperCase().contains('PDF'))  {

            extn= true;

                }

            else{
            extn= false;
            }            
    }




       if(extn == true){


    if(listToInsert.size() >= 0)
    {
        insert listToInsert ;
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, ' Records are uploaded successfully'));
        FileCount = '' ;
    }
    }
    else{
            listToInsert.clear();   //Changed by Max
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error, 'Attachment File type not allowed , allowed file types are jpg/jpeg/png/pdf'));
            return null;
        }




   // else
     //   ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Please select at-least one file'));
        }


        catch(Exception ex){
    ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
                          }

    return null;
}

 public PageReference ChangeCount()
{
    allFileList.clear() ;
    for(Integer i = 1 ; i <= Integer.valueOf(FileCount) ; i++)
        allFileList.add(new Attachment()) ;
    return null ;
}}
```

Comment: This snippet is for mulitple upload but in my case i want to upload one file only. Once I upload the file it should save into attachment and allow me to upload another one.

Comment: Remove the multiple file funcitonality

Comment: It didnt work....Once I upload the file without any save button I want to insert the file ...